# Export raster with one band only using gdalwarp in extracting raster using shapefile via python script? QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, gdalwarp, extract-by-mask

This code of mine is written to extract raster using a particular shapefile in PyQGIS:

```
import subprocess, os, glob, gdal
result_path = "/data/brent/bukidnon_hansen_data/result_path//"
os.chdir("/data/brent/bukidnon_hansen_data/bukidnon_forest_cover_hansen")
mask_layer = ("/data/brent/bukidnon_hansen_data/shp_files/AD_Kalatunganrange.shp")

for fname in glob.glob("*.tif"):
    input = os.path.join("/data/brent/bukidnon_hansen_data/bukidnon_forest_cover_hansen", fname)
    (pathshp, shpname) = os.path.split(mask_layer)
    (newName, ext) = os.path.splitext(shpname)
    warp = 'gdalwarp -cutline \'%s\' -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha \'%s\' \'%s\'' % (mask_layer, input, result_path+newName+fname)
    os.system(warp)
```

The output rasters had two bands, what I want are single band rasters.
I checked the gdalwarp documentation http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html but I can't find the arguments that should make the output raster as single band.

Perhaps I missed something?

The input tiffs are single band rasters.

Comment: @Joseph I'd removed the -dst alpha and it worked.

Comment: Nice one! Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Comment: That's what I would like to comment, so the answer  could served as a reference for others.  Again, much thanks.:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output raster has two bands because you are also including the alpha band (indicated by the `-dstalpha` parameter). If you don't need this band then you can remove the parameter so that it reads:

```
warp = 'gdalwarp -cutline \'%s\' -crop_to_cutline \'%s\' \'%s\'' % (mask_layer, input, result_path+newName+fname)
```

This should create an output raster with only one band.