# Extracting raster

Tags: qgis, python, raster, pyqgis

I've been using my own [code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250625/export-raster-with-one-band-only-using-gdalwarp-in-extracting-raster-using-shape) to extract multiple rasters using a single shapefile.

I've just substituted the strings (inputs, file paths etc.) to my code:

```
import subprocess, os, glob, gdal
result_path = "/home/brent/Documents/Hansen_new_data/New_data/10_110/NAMRIA_based//"
os.chdir("/home/brent/Documents/Hansen_new_data/New_data/10_110")
mask_layer = ("/home/brent/Documents/Hansen_new_data/NAMRIA_QGIS.shp")

for fname in glob.glob("*.tif"):
    input = os.path.join("/home/brent/Documents/Hansen_new_data/New_data/10_110/", fname)
    (pathshp, shpname) = os.path.split(mask_layer)
    (newName, ext) = os.path.splitext(shpname)
    warp = 'gdalwarp -cutline \'%s\' -crop_to_cutline -co compress=LZW \'%s\' \'%s\'' % (mask_layer, input, result_path+newName+fname)
    os.system(warp)
```

I wonder what went wrong because it's not working anymore. I'm using QGIS 2.18.

Comment: Maybe the creation options (`-co`) need to be in string format. I.e. `-co "compress=LZW"`.

Comment: hard to know what is wrong without an error or description of "not working" actually means (e.g., produces no output, produces garbage output)

Comment: also, i would recommend the `subprocess` module as it'll help you pass those arguments and capture the output

Comment: @PaulH, it produces no ouput but it seemed to iterate through the rasters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an invalid geometry for the shapefile mask I used that's why gdalwarp failed. I used [lwgeom plugin](https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=lwgeom+plugin&oq=lwgeom+plugin&aqs=chrome..69i57.3908j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).